# Make a variable read only, but still accessible by clients in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there any way to do this:

```
class example {
public:
   const int dontModifyMe;

   example() {
      // setup for dontModifyMe..
      dontModifyMe = getValueForDontModifyMe(earlierSetup);
   }
}

example ex;
cout << ex.dontModifyMe; // works
ex.dontModifyMe = 4 // error
```

If dontModifyMe didn't need setup, I would just use the member initialization list. Is there a way around this that doesn't require explicit getter/setter methods?

Comment: Why can't you have getter/setters?

Comment: Not an explicit setter, but a getter is.

Comment: Your sample code constructor should not compile.

Comment: That member is `const`, For user-defined construction like yours, it *has* to be in the member initialization list, so the idea of "I would..." should be "I have to...", and thereby considerably restricts your options if you want to expose a const member directly without a getter. Thus, you have to get creative with your setup function, as it will need to appear as the initialization value for `dontModifyMe` in the member initializer list if you intend on keeping `dontModifyMe` as you currently have it declared.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello for semantic reasons. Most members are public, and object.writableValue.nonWritableValue looks better than object.writableValue.getNonWritableValue().

Comment: It may look better, but you are breaking encapsulation, which has much more dire consequences for your design than a slight naming change. In my opinion, it looks about the same. Your assumption of "most members are public" is also false. Most data members should be private.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello I agree, most data members should be private. What I meant was that in my existing code, most of the members are public.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something that I have used in the past is along the lines of:

```
class example {
    int m_theValue;
public:
    const int &theValue = m_theValue; 
}
```

This allows you to edit the value internally via m_theValue while keeping a constant interface available in the "public" realm. It is similiar in effect of a getter/setter method, but doesn't require the actual usage of said methods.

Comment: Very interesting. I never would have thought of that.

Comment: @MichaelHagar Thanks, just something I found a while ago. I think it just makes a slightly more concise and elegant solution. (As compared to a getter/setter method)

Answer (score 2):

Example( compiled with gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) )

```
using namespace std;

int initializer( int c )
{
    return 4 * c;
}

class A
{
public:
    A() : v( initializer( 5 ) ) {}
    const int v;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    cout << "Result " << a.v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result

```
Result 20
```